# Debian Installation stucks at Configuring APT sources

Tags: debian, installation

I am trying to install Debian 10 using bootable USB drive and win-load but it stucks at Configuring APT sources...
I have installed Debian with the exact same USB drive on other machine successfully.

Comment: Welcome, could you add more details , your question is unclear.By *ATP sources* ,did you mean apt sources?

Comment: Oh sorry yes i mean apt.

Comment: What details do you mean exactly?

Comment: In my experience this is likely caused by network connectivity problems (non-working DNS; routing/IP address problems, proxy problems...). In the Debian installer, click `Go back` after the problem appears, from the main installer menu select `Execute a shell`, then inspect syslog contents (`cat /var/log/syslog`). Are there warnings or error messages relevant to the failing installation step?

Comment: Thank you @nodiscc that worked for me.

Comment: @ahmadsedigh no problem, what worked? I think you should update your question with the error messages you found in syslog, and how you fixed it. It will help others that may have the same problem. And mark the question as solved?

Comment: hi @nodiscc how can i mark your answer as solution to my question?

Comment: I have added it as an answer so you can mark it as resolved... but you still didn't provide the details. What was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this is likely caused by network connectivity problems (non-working DNS; routing/IP address problems, proxy problems...). In the Debian installer, click *Go back* after the problem appears, from the main installer menu select *Execute a shell*, then inspect syslog contents (`cat /var/log/syslog`). Are there warnings or error messages relevant to the failing installation step?